# Access postgres in matlab without database toolbox

Tags: matlab, postgresql, interface

I followed the steps listed in the previous answer to this question here

[How can I access a postgresql database from matlab with without matlabs database toolbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698159/how-can-i-access-a-postgresql-database-from-matlab-with-without-matlabs-database)

However, on the step

```
driver = org.postgresql.Driver;
```

I'm getting the following error.

Undefined variable "org" or function "org.postgresql.Driver"

I've added it to the dynamic path, and running "javaclasspath" shows the following at the bottom

```
    DYNAMIC JAVA PATH

M:\postgresql-9.3-1100.jdbc41.jar
```

any ideas on what is wrong?

Comment: try using `javaObject('org.postgresql.Driver')`. Does this raise a clear exception?

Comment: Here's what that outputs

Error using javaObject
No class org.postgresql.Driver can be located on the Java class path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably got the wrong bytecode-versin of postgresql. The `jdbc41` is for java 1.7 and 1.8 only, which is not included at least up to Matlab 13a. Only 13b has Java 1.7 with jdbc41 integrated.

Type `ver` to check your current JRE integrated into Matlab, then download the correct bytecode-version of postgresql, which is probably `jdbc4`.

Comment: you're right that solved it. I downloaded java 1.7 separately, but didn't realize matlab came with its own which was 1.6. Thanks!