# PostgreSQL: Why psql can't connect to server?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I typed `psql` and I get this:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I used `sudo netstat -nlp | grep 5432` to see the status but nothing showed.
And I searched online, somebody told me to modify `pg_hba.conf` but I can't `locate` this file. And I also tried this command `sudo ln -s /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432`. It can't work.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

The error states that the psql utility can't find the socket to connect to your database server. Either you don't have the database service running in the background, or the socket is located elsewhere, or perhaps the `pg_hba.conf` needs to be fixed.

#### Step 1: Verify that the database is running

The command may vary depending on your operating system. But on most *ix systems the following would work, it will search for postgres among all running processes

```
ps -ef | grep postgres
```

On my system, mac osx, this spits out

```
501   408     1   0  2Jul15 ??         0:21.63 /usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres -r /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log
```

The last column shows the command used to start the server, and the options.

You can look at all the options available to start the postgres server using the following.

```
man postgres
```

From there, you'd see that the options `-D` and `-r` are respectively the `datadir` & the `logfilename`.

#### Step 2: If the postgres service is running

Use `find` to search for the location of the socket, which should be somewhere in the `/tmp`

```
sudo find /tmp/ -name .s.PGSQL.5432
```

If postgres is running and accepting socket connections, the above should tell you the location of the socket. On my machine, it turned out to be:

```
/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

Then, try connecting via psql using this file's location explicitly, eg.

```
psql -h /tmp/ dbname
```

#### Step 3: If the service is running but you don't see a socket

If you can't find the socket, but see that the service is running, Verify that the pg_hba.conf file allows local sockets.

Browse to the `datadir` and you should find the `pg_hba.conf` file.

By default, near the bottom of the file you should see the following lines:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local       all       all       trust
```

If you don't see it, you can modify the file, and restart the postgres service.

Comment: I was concerned that this may not apply to my situation. I had no pg_hba.conf at all anywhere, but still had a locally functioning postgresql server. Using this answer, and consulting https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html for additional remote access options worked great. Thanks @Haleemur Ali!

Comment: Command to restart postgres: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52610486/9843399

Comment: I followed all these instructions as my service showed the same message after I tried to `sudo -u postgres psql`. Since I am a beginner at Linux and command line in general, after a lot of `man` here this `man` that I finally found that a simple run of `find /var/run/ | grep postgres` and the process would show up, right?
I found this: `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433`
It's on 5433!
`sudo -u postgres -p 5433` and BOOM - you're ready to go again :)

Comment: step one gives me `user   3251  2963  0 17:31 pts/4    00:00:00 grep --color=auto postgres` on Ubuntu20.04 on wsl2 (the postgres is colored red). what does this mean?

Comment: @tenshi this is the search command (`grep`) that you ran (including the default options of `--color=auto`). If there are no other lines then postgresql is not running.

Comment: You can get to this page simply because postgres is not running on default port and then this answer is a bit misleading. You should change the port by a wildcard * in the find.
If the port is not default this command will help :

PGPORT=5433; export PGPORT

Comment: This is what I called, chain of thought reasoning. Thanks Man! are you sure, you are not an LLM?

Comment: What if the server isn't running? - This happed to me. First try run the server manually to see if that is really the case, by running `postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data`. If the server is running and you can run psql normally, then you just need to set up the server running whenever your system is booting up by using `systemd`. I followed [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/server-start.html).

Answer (score 106):

If there is no error in starting the Postgres service, follow these steps

### Step 1: Running `pg_lsclusters` will list all the Postgres clusters running on your device

eg:

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.6 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log
```

most probably the status will be down in your case. If not restart PostgreSQL service

### Step 2: Restart the pg_ctlcluster

```
#format is pg_ctlcluster <version> <cluster> <action>
sudo pg_ctlcluster 9.6 main start

#restart PostgreSQL service
sudo service postgresql restart
```

### Step 3: Step 2 failed and threw an error

If restarting pg_lsclusters was not successful, it will throw an  error.
My error was(You can see the errors in the logs `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log`)

```
FATAL: could not access private key file "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key": Permission denied
Try adding `postgres` user to the group `ssl-cert`
```

### Step 4: check ownership of postgres

Make sure that `postgres` is the owner of `/var/lib/postgresql/version_no/main`
eg: `sudo chown postgres -R /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/`

### Step 5: Check postgres user belongs to ssl-cert user group

It happened to me and it turned out that I removed erroneously the Postgres user from "ssl-cert" group. Run the below code to fix the user group issue and for fixing the permissions

```
#set user to group back with
sudo gpasswd -a postgres ssl-cert

# Fixed ownership and mode
sudo chown root:ssl-cert  /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
sudo chmod 740 /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

# now postgresql starts! (and install command doesn't fail anymore)
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Comment: Thanks 86546546 times.

Comment: Step 4 solved my problem

Comment: `pg_ctlcluster/pg_lsclusters command not found`. Using CentOS 8.

Answer (score 64):

I experienced this issue when working with PostgreSQL on Ubuntu 18.04.

I checked my `PostgreSQL` status and realized that it was running fine using:

```
sudo systemctl status postgresql
```

I also tried restarting the `PotgreSQL` server on the machine using:

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

but the issue persisted:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

**Following [Noushad' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49860500/10907864) I did the following**:

List all the Postgres clusters running on your device:

```
pg_lsclusters
```

this gave me this output in red colour, showing that they were all down and the status also showed **down**:

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
10  main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/10/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
11  main    5433 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/11/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log
12  main    5434 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
```

Restart the pg_ctlcluster for one of the server clusters. For me I restarted **PG 10**:

```
sudo pg_ctlcluster 10 main start
```

It however threw the error below, and the same error occurred when I tried restarting other PG clusters:

```
Job for postgresql@10-main.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration.
See "systemctl status postgresql@10-main.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Check the log for errors, in this case mine is **PG 10**:

```
sudo nano /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
```

I saw the following error:

```
2020-09-29 02:27:06.445 WAT [25041] FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/10/main" has group or world access
2020-09-29 02:27:06.445 WAT [25041] DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700).
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

This was caused because I made changes to the file permissions for the PostgreSQL data directory.

I fixed it by running the command below. I ran the command for the 3 PG clusters on my machine:

```
sudo chmod -R 0700 /var/lib/postgresql/10/main
sudo chmod -R 0700 /var/lib/postgresql/11/main
sudo chmod -R 0700 /var/lib/postgresql/12/main
```

Afterwhich I restarted each of the PG clusters:

```
sudo pg_ctlcluster 10 main start
sudo pg_ctlcluster 11 main start
sudo pg_ctlcluster 12 main start
```

And then finally I checked the health of clusters again:

```
pg_lsclusters
```

this time around everything was fine again as the status showed **online**:

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
10  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/10/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
11  main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/11/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log
12  main    5434 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: thank you very much, this line `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log` just saved me. One can find a lot of information about the log files under `/var/lib/postgres/13/main/log/` but after 3 days of research I did not found anything about the main log file and now I see in the main log that my `server.crt` ee key too small. Just creating new `crt` with 2048 bits worked for me

Comment: In my case I simply deleted the clusters for older versions of postgres as I had no worries about data loss. After that psql could connect fine with latest version server. 1) List all clusters: ps_lscluster 2) delete older version clusters: pg_dropcluster <oldder version> <name>

Answer (score 48):

In my case the following worked for starting postgres after running into the error

```
sudo service postgresql start
sudo su - postgres
psql
```

Comment: This did not work

Comment: Worked on version 14, Ubuntu 20

Comment: Thanks, "sudo su - postgres" it is what I need it, my error was on trying to access, my service was online, but did now how to access! Thanks

Comment: But why did it work ?

Answer (score 33):

I have encountered a similar issue a couple of times. Normally I just do a fresh installation of PostgreSQL following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-16-04/) and that solves the problem at the expense of losing data.

I was determined on getting real fix today. Restarting PostgreSQL resolved it on ubuntu. `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart`

Answer (score 20):

There are various potential factors that may contribute to the inability of psql to establish a connection with a PostgreSQL server in a WSL 2 Ubuntu environment.

To check your Postgresql is running, use this command

```
sudo service postgresql status
```

If it is not running you can start it by using

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

And if you made changes in Postgresql config to apply changes by

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Answer (score 15):

I was facing same problem and

```
sudo su - postgres
initdb --locale en_US.UTF-8 -D /var/lib/postgres/data
exit
sudo systemctl start postgresql
sudo systemctl status postgresql
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

Solved it! Although I don't know what happened, but I just deleted all the stuff and reinstalled it. This is the command I used to delete it `sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql\*` and `dpkg -l | grep postgres`. The latter one is to find all the packets in case it is not clean.

Comment: Note for other readers: that this deletes your configuration (at least), so don't just blindly run this command. In most cases there's something specific wrong, like the server simply not having been started up, and you should fix the specific problem rather than purging and reinstalling everything.

Comment: Thanks, my postgres on an ec2 instance wouldn't start anymore. That did the trick. Since it was a dev server I didn't mind losing the data.

Answer (score 5):

quick howto on debian to remotely access postgres database on server from the psql client: (the changed config is doc'd in the files):

1. edit `/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf` with listen_address *
2. edit `/etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf` and add line in the end with `host all all 0/0 md5`
3. create login role `postgres=# CREATE ROLE remoteuser LOGIN WITH PASSWORD 'foo'`
4. `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart` changes take effect
5. login from clientside with `psql --host=ipofserver --port=5432 --username=remoteuser --password --dbname=mydb`
6. the password is interactivly asked which in this case is foo

Answer (score 5):

I resolved this problem by checking my file system
the disk was completely full, and so database could not start up

connections on Unix domain socket `"/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" ?`

I tried series of troubleshooting, until when i checked my disk usage and found that it was full, 100% usage,

```
df -h
cd /var/log/odoo/
cat /dev/null > odoo-server.log
reboot
```

Comment: I wouldn't have thought of that, so thank you. I have a script that makes a backup of all my databases every night and eventually the disk was full and it was causing this error.

Answer (score 3):

The error means that the Postgres server is not running. Try starting it:

```
sudo systemctl start postgresql
```

Make sure that the server starts on boot:

```
sudo systemctl enable postgresql
```

Comment: Was about to comment this as it worked for me immediately and then found yours.  

Let's get this answer unburied.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using windows subsystem for linux and Ruby on Rails  then check  your postgres is running in which port using this command
`sudo nano /etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf` if it is in port 5433 then go to database.yml file and add port:5433 in there
and then run command `sudo service postgresql start`
i have resolved my issue like this

Answer (score 3):

I believe I fell into this issue after uninstalling PostgreSQL 11 and 12 while already installed 13 on on Ubuntu 21. I just solved this issue by `sudo nano /etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf`, and found that `port = 5433` (don't know why). So I changed `port = 5432`. Then problem solved.

Comment: I met the same problem... is pg 13 using 5433 port ?

Comment: Probably by default it will try to use 5432, but it was likely that port 5432 already in use by existing process (such as previous version of PostgreSQL or similar process "detected",) which make it attempt to choose 5433 (incrementally).

Answer (score 3):

From the command line run: `pg_isready`

```
> pg_isready 
/run/postgresql:5432 - accepting connections
```

This will show if postgresql is connected on a local socket and accepting connections.

A [Connection URI](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/libpq-connect.html) of:

`"host=/run/postgresql dbname=your_db_name"`

should work for clients trying to connect locally.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on Devuan ascii (maybe Debian, too?). The config file `/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf` contains a directive `unix_socket_directories` which points to `/var/run/postgresql` by default. Changing it to `/tmp`, where most clients look by default, fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

OK in my case, I uninstalled postgres 10 , but not successfully ,some pg10 file/process still remains there.

and then I installed postgres 13, so pg 13 think there is another pg running on port 5432, so it's using 5433.

solution:  purge all your pg via: `sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql postgresql-*`
and then re-install it. ( caution: this will remove all your existing data )

Comment: This was the only solution which worked for me. The reason may have been that I have multiple versions of postgresql installed.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.
I was worried about the socket connection because i was using:

```
psql -U postgres db_omm < db.pgsql
```

and the error was:
Error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"

But the authentication uses the user permissions. So even if you specify the user and you are in root or other one, you have to switch to postgres

```
su - postgres
```

Then it worked!

Comment: su - postgres worked for me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

My issue with this error message was in wrong permissions on key and pem certificates, which I have manipulated. What helped me a lot was:
/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log where are all the errors.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
It seems that there is no socket when there is no cluster.

The default cluster creation failed during the installation because no default locale was set.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue! I lost several hours searching for a solution and was thinking about asking a new question but it was worth checking less popular answers. Indeed the command pg_lsclusters was complaining about missing locale variables that were not set so I had to set them in /etc/default/locale. Maybe this is a bug that should be reported to PostgreSQL, there should be a fallback when there is no default locale set.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had this error, `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433` (note, one number up from the file it was looking for, `.s.PGSQL.5432`) was present. Tried the instructions at the top of this page but nothing worked.

Turns out there was an old directory for PostGreSQL 12 config files in `/etc/postgresql/12`, which I deleted, which solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to make a small addition: if your instance is complaining on a socket, you can also check `unix_socket_directories` at `/data/postgresql.conf` file which could have been set to `/tmp`, for example, if you have used a 3rd party distribution. You can change it to `/var/run/postgresql` and restart the service. That may also require creating a `postgresql` dir at `/var/run` and `subsys/postgresql-9.6` at `/var/lock` if those doesn't already exist (worked for me with postgresql 9.6).

Answer (score 0):

During fresh installation of postgresql. By default, user name and password is assigned as "postgres". The feature this RDBMS provides is to add role for new user and create database. If you are getting such errors:

1. login in by default username:

   root@kalilinux:~# sudo -i -u postgres
2. ype psql for interactive prompt

   postgres@kalilinux:~$ psql
3. To quit from prompt use

   \q
4. To create new user role

   postgres@kalilinux:~$ createuser --interactive

Now you are in interacive psql shell. Enjoy. Dont forget to login in from your username and type psql for shell.

Answer (score 0):

It can cause anything for example, my issue was caused for typo error on configuration files.
Some of people says caused by certificate files, another group says caused by unmatched locals.

If you cant find any solution about your issue, remove postgres and reinstall it.This is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue and the problem was in the config file pg_hba.conf. I had earlier made some changes which was causing the server to error out while trying to start it. Commenting out the extra additions solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the instance worked for me. Also, as mentioned in some other post psql -h '/tmp' worked as well before the restart. But post restart psql  directly started working. 
So, probably some file ownership issues that got reset with the restart is what I am thinking.

Answer (score 0):

If your service is not secure, this may be the reason

```
vi /etc/postgresql/11/main/pg_hba.conf
```

1. open hba config file, this config file usualy located in the **etc** directory.

```
host    all   all    localhost trust   md5
```

2. you can remove the **trust** keyword
3. save pg_hba.conf
4. sudo service postgresql restart.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that Postgres is running using:

```
ps -ef | grep postgres
```

```
root@959dca34cc6d:/var/lib/edb# ps -ef|grep postgres
enterpr+    476  1  0 06:38 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/edb-as/11/bin/edb-postgres -D /var/lib/edb-as/11/main2 -c config_file=/etc/edb-as/11/main2/postgresql.conf
```

Check for data directory and `postgresql.conf`.

In my case data directory in `-D` was different than that in `postgresql.conf`

So I changed the data directory in `postgresql.conf` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this by setting the right permissions to datadir.
It should be

```
chmod 700 /var/lib/postgresql/10/main
chown postgres.postgres /var/lib/postgresql/10/main
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the service was running but the cluster was down and psql wouldn't start.  My configuration files looked perfect but it kept throwing configuration errors and seemed to ignore the changes I was making.

It turns out that whenever you use `ALTER SYSTEM SET ...` syntax, PostgreSQL writes to a file called `postgresql.auto.conf`.  That file is read *in addition to* the regular `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` files.  In my distribution of Ubuntu (18.04), they are in different folders(!):
- `pg_hba.conf` and `postgresql.conf` are both in `/etc/postgresql/12/main`
- The auto-generated file is `/var/lib/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.auto.conf`

I had tried to change the configuration using `ALTER SYSTEM SET listen_addresses = <my-ip>`, but had made a mistake and that created a broken "ghost" configuration that I couldn't find.  As soon as I erased the offending line in `postgresql.auto.conf`, it fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I saw this error and postgres was **not** running.

The problem was that the instalation failed to create the required cluster.

The solution was to create the folder `/etc/postgres/{postgresql-version}/main`

and then create the cluster with:

```
pg_createcluster {postgresql-version} main
```

After that wiht just restarting the postgresql service everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

on rebooting the server i found these in 2 locations

srwxrwxrwx   1 postgres postgres    0 Nov 10 18:44 .s.PGSQL.5432
-rw-------   1 postgres postgres   48 Nov 10 18:44 .s.PGSQL.5432.lock

both these files were present in below locations and were not present before reboot
/var/run/postgresql/
/tmp/

make sure these files with the corresponding permissions are available and start the psql

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to set up the credentials in the config/database.yml under the default database.

```
username: <%= ENV["PG_USERNAME"] %>
password: <%= ENV["PG_PASSWORD"] %>
```

[image: Picture of code to be added]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

So for me and my pals working on a Node.js app (with Postgres and Sequelize), we had to

1. `brew install postgresql` (one of us was missing postgres, one of us was not, and yet we were getting the same error msg as listed above)
2. `brew services start postgresql` **** (utilize Homebrew to start postgres)
3. `createdb <name of database in config.json file>`
4. `node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate`
5. `npm start`

Answer (score -2):

This command works for me on Ubuntu machine

sudo su -postgres

it would request for your password to be entered, most likely your default password.

Answer (score -2):

I know my answer is too late, but I think it can help someone.

I did get his issue when I was modifying the `pg_hba.conf` to recover password. I am running Debian GNU/Linux. Here's what I did:

- backup `pg_hba.conf` to `pg_hba.conf.bk`
- edit the file
- restart the server
- everything ok

But, when I want to recover the backup file:

- rename `pg_hba.conf` to `pg_hba.conf_no_pass`
- rename `pg_hba.conf.bk` to `pg_hba.conf`
- restart the server
- I get the error above.

So, to fix, I just renamed `pg_hba.conf_no_pass` to `pg_hba.conf` and edit the file as it was before. After restarting the server, everything was just fine.

Answer (score -3):

This is problem occurs with me sometime we add some back up folder, log file folder , scripts ,some certain dependency in postgresql.conf file if this no exist they cause may  problem