# Where is pg_hba.conf is located in Manjaro

Tags: postgresql, manjaro

So, I have installed PostgreSQL 10.1 in my Linux Manjaro 17.1.1 using yaourt installer package.

```
yaourt -S postgresql
```

From here I can't connect the database locally, so, when searching I found [this stackoverflow posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645550/why-psql-cant-connect-to-server) which tells me that I should find `pg_hba.conf` file (step 3)

I tried to find the `pg_hba.conf` file using this command in terminal

```
sudo find / -name *pg_hba*`
```

but still can't find the file, instead I only found a sample file here:

```
/usr/share/postgresql/pg_hba.conf.sample
```

I tried to reinstall the package using yaourt again, but still it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

So, here is the error that I get when trying to connect to the database.

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I just solve the problem a few minutes after I posted it. And stupid me, I didn't read carefully the instruction from [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PostgreSQL).

Apparently, I need some more steps to finish the installation. I need to run the command below:

> Before PostgreSQL can function correctly, the database cluster must be
>   initialized:
>
> ```
> [postgres]$ initdb --locale $LANG -E UTF8 -D '/var/lib/postgres/data'
> ```

Then, start and enable the `postgresql.service`:

> As root, start and enable `postgresql.service`. See #Upgrading
>   PostgreSQL for necessary steps before installing new versions of the
>   PostgreSQL packages.

Now, after the installation finished, I can find the config file using the command below.

`sudo find / -name pg_hba.conf`