# How to access Odoo 14 using WSL

Tags: postgresql, odoo, windows-subsystem-for-linux, odoo-14

I have installed Odoo 14 in Ubuntu 20LTS as WSL, everything seems fine and the service is running. However, I am lost on how to access Odoo page. I have tried 0.0.0.0:8069 in Windows (Chrome) but it says that:

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Any help on that?

Also, please let me know how I can change the Port for Odoo in Ubuntu in WSL.

Many Thanks.

Comment: What does your Odoo log say. You'll get some hints from there. How everything seems fine? And for changing port is done in odoo.conf. But if you want to run your Odoo on port 80 or 443, I'd use Nginx or Apache to do reverse proxy. They are a bit tricky to setup because of longpoll queries though.

Comment: It's not an Odoo specific issue. I would check out the discussions on issues like https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4885 to see how people access localhost. Some say use your local IP instead, some talk about restarting WSL, some say upgrading to WSL2.

Comment: odoo: Odoo version 14.0
odoo: addons paths: ['/home/bassemwolsely/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo/addons', '/home/bassemwolsely/.local/share/Odoo/addons/14.0', '/home/bassemwolsely/odoo-dev/odoo/addons']
odoo: database: default@default:default
odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: You need Wkhtmltopdf to print a pdf version of the reports.
odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on Dell.localdomain:8069
base odoo.modules.loading: loading 7 modules...
base odoo.modules.loading: 7 modules loaded in 0.06s, 0 queries (+0 extra)
base odoo.modules.loading: Modules loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to my problem :
[PostgreSQL: Why psql can't connect to server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645550/postgresql-why-psql-cant-connect-to-server)

Step 5: Check postgres user belongs to ssl-cert user group
It happened to me and it turned out that I removed erroneously the Postgres user from "ssl-cert" group. Run the below code to fix the user group issue and for fixing the permissions

`````
sudo gpasswd -a postgres ssl-cert

# Fixed ownership and mode
sudo chown root:ssl-cert  /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
sudo chmod 740 /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

# now postgresql starts! (and install command doesn't fail anymore)
sudo service postgresql restart````
`````