# System has not been booted with systemd ERROR when updating Postgresql in Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-18.04

I've been following this link to update Postgresql on my Ubuntu-18.04 (VM running on Windows 10)
https://computingforgeeks.com/install-postgresql-12-on-ubuntu/

However, Im getting the below error, so I cannot proceed.

```
.../desktop/my_app$ systemctl status postgresql.service
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

service postgresql status
or
systemctl status postgresql

Must work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645550/postgresql-why-psql-cant-connect-to-server) and worked, but your ```service postgresql status``` also seems to work.