# PostgreSQL problem: System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1)

Tags: postgresql

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

I tried to follow [PostgreSQL: Why psql can't connect to server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645550/postgresql-why-psql-cant-connect-to-server) but after typing

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

I get:

```
 * Starting PostgreSQL 14 database server                                                                                * Error: /usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/14/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log -s -o  -c config_file="/etc/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf"  exited with status 1:
2021-12-13 10:54:29.791 CET [180] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.1 (Ubuntu 14.1-2.pgdg20.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, 64-bit
2021-12-13 10:54:29.797 CET [180] LOG:  could not bind IPv4 address "127.0.0.1": Permission denied
2021-12-13 10:54:29.798 CET [180] WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
2021-12-13 10:54:29.798 CET [180] FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
2021-12-13 10:54:30.039 CET [180] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

After: sudo find /tmp/ -name .s.PGSQL.5432 -> nothing
After: sudo systemctl status postgresql -> System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

How to fix it? I am trying to install chirpstack LoraWAN server

Comment: Try `sudo systemctl start postgresql@14-main.service`

Comment: In this on hardware or docker?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. It seems like you are using *Ubuntu* in wsl3 like me.

```
ps -p 1 -o comm=
```

If you get `init` after the above command, then it means your ubuntu uses SysV instead of systemd. You can use the below commands.

```
sudo service postgresql status
sudo service postgresql start
sudo service postgresql stop
```

Comment: it works, i was on wsl too