# how to solve project setup error in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  database "mydatabase_development" not exist

when i run ***rake db:create***

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31647044/2483313

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This often happens because of [this issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/35240). If you are on MacOS and have Postgres installed via homebrew then you have two things you should try:

```
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

will try to upgrade your database using homebrew's built-in script. All your data from your previous work will be preserved.

Otherwise a usually more effective but dangerous approach (you will lose your local databases) is:

```bash
rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres && \
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8 && \
brew services restart postgresql && \
createdb $(whoami)
```