# connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I´am deploying my new app to heroku and i can´t figure out how can i solve it. I have this error:

**connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?**

I tried many things even redo complete database deploy.
On localhost everithing is working but if i want to deploy to heroku this appear.
Here is github repo to this project:
https://github.com/AdrianHorvath8/Developer-search

Comment: Check this it may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31645550/6150881

Answer (score -4):

I have gone through this process before. I would highly recommend following the steps in this article: https://medium.com/@hdsingh13/deploying-django-app-on-heroku-with-postgres-as-backend-b2f3194e8a43.

It explains exactly what you need to do to deploy your web application to Heroku w/ Django and Postgres.