# EDB lasso failing to connect to postgres server on debian

Tags: postgresql, edb

no command that I type in seems to be working. I keep receiving the following output:

> ```
> ./lasso-linux-x86_64 -p 5434  2022-09-23T09:48:29+0100 INFO EDB Lasso
> 4.3.0 PostgreSQL connection error connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5434" failed: No such file or directory
>
>    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
> ```

How could I mitigate this?

Comment: Check this, it may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31645550/6150881

Answer (score 0):

You can execute lasso report using the below format try to connect any db running on postgres cluster, that will execute this command.

```
./lasso-linux-x86_64 -H /tmp -p 5444 <DBNAME>
```

Note: If the socket is not present in /tmp, you may connect using any socket reported by SHOW unix_socket_directories, as well as localhost for the host argument, -H.