# Issues connecting to postgres

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

```
ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    at Client._connectionCallback (/home/gene/capital_greek_project/api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:131:24)
    at Client._handleErrorWhileConnecting (/home/gene/capital_greek_project/api/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:305:19)
    at Client._handleErrorEvent (/home/gene/capital_greek_project/api/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:315:19)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Socket.reportStreamError (/home/gene/capital_greek_project/api/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:52:12)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  parent: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) {
    errno: -111,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 5432
  }
```

I've been getting this error and I've been having a hard to time trying to connect to postgres using node js. I'm using Sequelize to define my models, I feel like it has something to do with my Ip address or my local host machine but I'm not sure how to navigate to it. Do I need to install postgres on to my machine ?

//******db.config.js*****

```
module.exports = {
  HOST: 'localhost',

  USER: 'postgres',

  PASSWORD: '123',

  DB: 'capital-greek',

  dialect: 'postgres',

  pool: {
    max: 5,

    min: 0,

    acquire: 30000,

    idle: 10000,
  },
};
```

//*****server.js******

```
const express = require('express');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

let corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:8081',
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// parse requests of content-type - application/json

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// database

const db = require('./app/models');

const Role = db.role;

// db.sequelize.sync()

// force: true will drop the table if it already exists

db.sequelize.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {
  console.log('Drop and Resync Database with { force: true }');

  initial();
});

// simple route

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: 'Welcome to bezkoder application.' });
});

// routes

require('./app/routes/auth.routes.js')(app);
require('./app/routes/users.routes.js')(app);

// set port, listen for requests

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});

function initial() {
  Role.create({
    id: 1,

    name: 'user',
  });

  Role.create({
    id: 2,

    name: 'moderator',
  });

  Role.create({
    id: 3,

    name: 'admin',
  });
}
```

//*****models/index.js*****

```
const config = require('../config/db.config.js');

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.DB, config.USER, config.PASSWORD, {
  host: config.HOST,

  dialect: config.dialect,

  operatorsAliases: 0,

  pool: {
    max: config.pool.max,

    min: config.pool.min,

    acquire: config.pool.acquire,

    idle: config.pool.idle,
  },
});

const db = {};

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

db.sequelize = sequelize;

db.user = require('../models/user.model.js')(sequelize, Sequelize);

db.role = require('../models/role.model.js')(sequelize, Sequelize);

db.role.belongsToMany(db.user, {
  through: 'user_roles',

  foreignKey: 'roleId',

  otherKey: 'userId',
});

db.user.belongsToMany(db.role, {
  through: 'user_roles',

  foreignKey: 'userId',

  otherKey: 'roleId',
});

db.ROLES = ['user', 'admin', 'moderator'];

module.exports = db;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your Postgres server allows for connection from your IP address?

Try modifying your's `pg_hba.conf` file by adding following lines:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    all             all             192.168.1.11/24        scram-sha-256
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

Section for this should be located near 86 line

You could find this file under:
`C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\(your postgres version)\data`

There is possibility that your configuration disallows connection from `127.0.0.1` (localhost).

You should probably replace `192.168.1.11` with your local ip

And I'm guessing that from this error description:
`Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help, I tried this and also found out that the server was down by viewing my clusters.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution that worked for me from another post, here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/31647044/18759005 . The problem was my postgres server was down. I have another solution to get the postgres server running which is from this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/49860500/18759005 , I only implemented step 1 & 2 . Both of these links are from the same question that is similar to mine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).